# AppsFlyer build fail on xcode6.4

Tags: appsflyer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV59X.png)

my project integrate AppsFlyer， it is ok on xcode7,xcode8，but it build fail on xcode6.4，and wrong info like picture. i don't know how to do , who can help me!

thanks

Comment: Why do you use Xcode6.4?  You can post error

Comment: because my project is a old project, it not upgrade to xcode8，and i had deal this issue, using old AppsFlyer version can fix it .